# How to read files from a torrent file?

Tags: c++, bittorrent

I want to extract information about torrent file like: files names inside it, their sizes ..., is there a `C++` library for `Linux` that help me achieve this easily? or what is the structure of a torrent file and how do I find these information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [libtorrent](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/) library—a feature complete C++ BitTorrent implementation focusing on efficiency and scalability.

If you want to write your own library, there is the official [BitTorrent Protocol Specification](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) but it is very poorly written and lacks a lot of details. There is also a much better [specification](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification) available.

Comment: Libtorrent seems good. Also there is an already compiled version of it for OpenWrt which is exactly what I need.